# How can I use CSS to code a 3-sided box (no left side) with rounded corners and a shadow?

Tags: css

I want my box to look like this except for the left side to be blank:

```
.box{
    width: 190px;
    height: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 50px;
}

#box4sides{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #dbdbdb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #DBDBDB;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #DBDBDB;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCC;
}
```

Here is my best attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/7dpUA/2/

I found other examples of 3-sided boxes, but they were with either the top or bottom removed, and I haven't been able to translate that to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper div around the box with **overflow** as **hidden** and give a **negative margin** for the *#box4sides* div.

Check this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7dpUA/22/

Is this what you need?

Comment: Cool, thanks for your idea.  I tweaked it to learn what was going on, and then I converted it to SCSS: http://jsfiddle.net/7dpUA/23/ I think this will work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to remove the class `shadow` from your 3 sided box and add this bit of css on your 3-sided box.

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 #DBDBDB, 1px -1px 1px 0 #DBDBDB;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
```

Explanation of the box-shadow property:
`box-shadow: 1 2 3 4 color;`

1. Horizontal Offset - Positive values move the shadow right, negatives left.
2. Vertical Offset - Positive values move the shadow down, negatives up.
3. Blur Radius - The larger the value, the blurrier it is.
4. Spread Distance - Positive values expand the shadow, negatives contract.

Color is pretty self-explanatory. **[Here is your jsFiddle edited to show what you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/7dpUA/6/)**

As far as the shadow is concerned, you don't need `position: relative;` anymore either.

Comment: That is close, but there is still a border or shadow visible on the left side, and the left corners are still round.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This looks good, though I found another answer to be easier to understand / implement.  I really appreciate this alternative though and may use it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Is [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/9afLV/) what you're looking for?  I exaggerated the borders and such for emphasis and increased the first argument on the shadow element to throw it to the right a bit, avoiding a "false border" effect.

Comment: @ryan re: your comment on Aust's answer, to square off the corners on the left side, change the border radius to border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;